# 12.04 on Intel Celeron NUC. Can't boot from drive if I move it to another

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, uefi

I have two identical NUCs, boot from USB CD, install the OS, works fine. Install was not adding any drivers or 3rd party apps.
 Take the same mSATA drive to the other NUC, and it won't boot. I have tried 32 and 64 bit. 
Checked to make the sure the drive is seen in the BIOS (it is). Have tried uncecking in the BIOS UEFI and Legacy, to no avail.

I have had two other people confirm the same thing on their own systems.

Comment: Could you change NUC for the complete term. A google search gave me 5 unrelated results.

Answer (score 0):

EFI relies on NVRAM entries to point it to boot loaders. See [this page,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) and in particular the section entitled "The EFI Boot Process," for details. To fix your problem you must either create new NVRAM entries by using an emergency disc and `efibootmgr` (or a similar tool in another OS or environment) or install a boot loader as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` (assuming an x86-64 CPU and 64-bit EFI).